# Android Dev - Run top command output to TextView

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview, command, output

I have been reading a lot this forum , and it help me a lot to setup my application , however , I do have another problem now , what I am trying to do is to display the "top" command output in a textview.
So layout is basically two buttons ( Start and Stop ) and a textView, and I have read here that I have to use an async task to run the command , up to here fine , now the problem is how to parse the output in order to display it correctly ? 
The result I want is a small textview displaying the top command result ( same output as running the command in a terminal )

```
public class Async extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>
{
private View rootView;
private Activity rootAct;
public Async(View view,Activity act) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub\
    View rootView = view;
    rootAct = act;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    Log.d("PRE-EXECUTE", "OK");
}



@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    Log.d("ON CANCEL", "OK");
}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    //Execution en BackGround
    Log.d("BACKGROUND", "START");
    Log.d("BACK PARAM 0", params[0]);
    Log.d("BACK PARAM 1", params[1]);

        try {
            // Executes the command.
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top");
            // Reads stdout.
            // NOTE: You can write to stdin of the command using
            //       process.getOutputStream().
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            int read;
            char[] buffer = new char[4096];
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
            while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.append(buffer, 0, read);
                publishProgress(output.toString());


            }
            reader.close();



            return null;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }



@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

    Log.d("UPDATE", "START");
    Log.d("RESUL", values[0]);

    TextView sortie = (TextView) rootAct.findViewById(R.id.txt_output);


        sortie.setText(values[0]);




    Log.d("UPDATE", "STOP");

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    Log.d("POSTEXE", "OK");

}

}
```

Therefore , what I would like is my textView to display the top command result and update everytime a new "starting" line exist , well not sure it is very clear , in fact the easier example would be open a terminal command on your phone type top in it and I would like the exact same output ...

I hope someone will be able to help me on that project ! ( and sorry for my horrible english , I'm french :) )

Best Regards,

EDIT : In fact, I just need a way to read the buffer and to append line to my output except if there is 3 "\n" in a row , is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , in fact after hours the only way I found is to parse it "old school" even if the result is not perfect...

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (line.isEmpty() && i == 2) {
                        Log.d("BACK", "Retour apres 3 espaces");
                        publishProgress(output.toString());
                        output.setLength(0);
                        i = 0;
                    } else if (line.isEmpty() && i == 1) {
                        Log.d("BACK", "2 espaces");
                        output.append("\n \n");
                        i = 2;
                    } else if (line.isEmpty() && i == 0) {
                        Log.d("BACK", "1 espaces");
                        output.append("\n \n");
                        i = 1;
                    } else {
                        Log.d("BACK", "LigneTxt");
                        output.append(line + "\n");
                        i = 0;
                    }
```

This seems to make the job , however the flow of data is not really fluid , therefore it's not really perfect if someone has an idea , I'am open to any comments ?